# Selecting an input tag with a name with multiple dots using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the following input tag

```
<input name="PostBack.Contract.ID" type="hidden" value="foo" />
```

and I need to change the value. I'm trying using the following statement but it doesn't work

```
$("input[type=hidden].PostBack.Contract.ID");
```

I get the following result

```
[]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$("input[type=hidden][name='PostBack.Contract.ID']");` But, why not simply use an `id` or `class` attributes? Anyway, see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @haim770 Hi, Thank you for your quick answer! It is the accepted answer! I know I can use an ID but I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and it uses the *name* attribute to do the binding in an **[HttpPost]** action so why to add an extra attribute?

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for your quick responses!

Comment: Because `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassname()` are performing way better than your current selector. Also, should your model/view-model property names change, your selector would break. By assigning a more definitive identifier to the element, you'll spare yourself from all this problems.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("input[type=hidden].PostBack.Contract.ID");
```

To:

```
$('input[name="PostBack.Contract.ID"]');
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ak5s5msn/)

Note that I have changed the input type to 'text' for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Select the element by `name` using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Check out following code ( I have changed input type to `text` so output can be seen easily ):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='PostBack.Contract.ID']").val("bar");
});//
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="PostBack.Contract.ID" type="text" value="foo" />
```

Comment: You miss a square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery  [**hidden-selector**](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
$( "input:hidden[name='PostBack.Contract.ID']" ).val() // Note the quotes
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7k1p0bmL/)